# Azure Functions timer trigger fires unstable

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

Our function app has TimerTrigger-function with CRON expression `*/10 * * * * *` (every 10 seconds), and periodically it seems like trigger stops to fire, only manual app restarting helps. We're sure that function wasn't fired because it should insert records into DB.

We're using .net6 (In-Process) and runtime v4, App Service Plan with 'Always On' enabled and disabled logging sampling.

Sample InvocationId: `74089037-5f8a-4f30-beca-0261aba58400`

You can see gaps in a timeline chart from Application Insights (all executions for last 48 hours).

[image]

Comment: have you followed this troubleshooting guide? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Investigating-and-reporting-issues-with-timer-triggered-functions-not-firing

Comment: yes, now I'm looking through additional troubleshooting https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#troubleshooting

Comment: @silent analyzed entire app logs, there was no any 'Singleton lock renewal failed' errors (from guide I mentioned above) for that app

Comment: Is your timer trigger function using the **RUNONSTARTUP** attribute if that is the case as per this [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/315#issuecomment-363873799), it is expected behavior.

Comment: we don't use that attribute for app

Comment: @dmgx0: Can you help me by Running Diagnose and Problems under that check Availability and Performance